# Confusing SBCL compiler message

Tags: sorting, common-lisp, compiler-warnings, sbcl

I'm receiving a SBCL compiler warning message, which I don't understand:

```
; file: D:/Users Data/Dave/SW Library/AI/Planning/DAB Planner/support.lisp
; in: DEFUN UPDATE-HAPPENINGS
;     (SORT PLANNER-PKG::HAP-UPDATES #'< :KEY #'CAR)
; ==>
;   (SB-IMPL::STABLE-SORT-LIST LIST
;                              (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN
;                               SB-C::PREDICATE)
;                              (IF SB-C::KEY
;                                  (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN SB-C::KEY)
;                                  #'IDENTITY))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of STABLE-SORT-LIST should not be discarded.
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of STABLE-SORT-LIST should not be discarded.
```

The source function generating this is as follows:

```
(defun update-happenings (state act-state)
  "Updates act-state with happenings up through the action completion time
  for all happenings, and checks for constraint violation along the way."
  (declare (problem-state state act-state) (special *happenings*))
  (when (null *happenings*)
    (return-from update-happenings act-state))
  (let* ((hap-state (copy-problem-state state))  ;initialization
         (net-state (copy-problem-state act-state))  ;initialization
         (obj-hap-updates (iter (for object in *happenings*)
                                (collect (get-object-happening-update object state
                                                    (problem-state-time act-state)))))
         (next-hap-update (iter (for obj-update in obj-hap-updates)
                                (finding obj-update maximizing (second (car obj-update)))))
         (hap-updates (iter (for obj-update in obj-hap-updates)
                            (append (cdr obj-update)))))
    (setf (problem-state-happenings net-state) (car next-hap-update))
    (setf hap-updates (sort hap-updates #'< :key #'car))
    (iter (for hap-update in hap-updates)  ;compute final net-state
          (revise (problem-state-db net-state) (cdr hap-update)))
    (iter (for hap-update in hap-updates)
          (revise (problem-state-db hap-state) (cdr hap-update))
          (when (constraint-violated act-state hap-state net-state)
            (return-from update-happenings nil))  ;cancel action and exit
          (finally (return net-state)))))  ;no constraint violations encountered
```

All of the compiler optimization parameters are set to 1. Does anyone have an explanation or suggestions for troubleshooting this further?

*Note: Edited to include entire function.*

Comment: How is `hap-updates` used in `...`?  The warning seems to indicate that the return value of `sort` is not used.

Comment: Based on Rainer Joswig's answer, here is a slightly smaller test case that demonstrates the issue: `(let ((a (list 10 10 9 10))) (sort a #'<) a)`. This evaluates to: `(10 10 10)`. That is, `a` does not contain the sorted result we need. The sorted result was the return value of `(sort a #'<)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SORT may have destructive and unwanted side-effects when sorting a list.

For example here we sort a list `(10 10 9 10)`

```
CL-USER> (funcall (lambda (&aux (a (list 10 10 9 10))) 
                     (sort a #'<)
                     a))
; in: FUNCALL (LAMBDA (&AUX (A (LIST 10 10 9 10))) (SORT A #'<) A)
;     (SORT A #'<)
; ==>
;   (SB-IMPL::STABLE-SORT-LIST LIST
;                              (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN
;                               SB-C::PREDICATE)
;                              (IF SB-C::KEY
;                                  (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-TO-FUN SB-C::KEY)
;                                  #'IDENTITY))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of STABLE-SORT-LIST should not be discarded.
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The return value of STABLE-SORT-LIST should not be discarded.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
(10 10 10)
```

You can see that the list pointed to by `a` is not the result and its contents have been altered.

You can see the differences:

```
CL-USER> (funcall (lambda (&aux (a (list 10 10 9 10))) 
            (values (sort a #'<)
                    a)))
(9 10 10 10)     ;    this is the result from SORT
(10 10 10)       ;    this is the side-effected value of A
```

SBCL warns that the code does not use the result value. It's also wrong to use the side-effected list after sorting.

You should check the code and see if that is the case.

Comment: But the next statement does use the sorted result: `(iter (for hap-update in hap-updates) (revise (problem-state-db net-state) (cdr hap-update)))`.

Comment: @davypough: that's why one need to see more of the source code. Especially the whole function.

Comment: Still don't get it. I've edited my original post to include the entire function, in case this clarifies the source of the warning. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: @davypough: is that the only warning? Is ITERATE loaded?

Comment: @daypough: it could also be a compiler bug.

Comment: Yes, that's the only warning, and `iterate` is loaded and working. Also note `stable-sort` issues no warning, so guess it doesn't use `sort`. Thanks for helping track it down.

Comment: @davypough: note from the warning, that it inlines SORT and the warning is about the inlined version.

Comment: Finally! It looks like SBCL was right all along. The sequence I was passing to `sort` was always `nil`, since my iterate statement producing that sequence mistakenly specified `append` rather than `collect` as an accumulator. Impressive. @Rainer Joswig, appreciate you walking me thru this.

Comment: I'm still bedeviled by this, however, since passing a null sequence to `sort` does not generate a SBCL compiler warning. I now think there is some unusual interaction between the SBCL compiler and the iterate library. Changing to the standard `loop` macro (using `append` for the accumulator, equivalent to the iter form) does not generate a warning.